# Auto populate drop down with Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I have branch registration form, inside my form I have two drop down fields `company_id` & `sub_agent_id`.

I want the `sub_agent_id` field to be auto populated based on what the users selected in `company_id` field.

Assume the user select `company_a` which has an `id` of 1 in my `company` field, then on my `sub_agent_id` field must show all the data (automatically) which has a value of `1` in my `sub_agent` entity and so on and so forth.

I have found a good article about this in symfony, [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data) but I must say I'm still a rookie and i cant find to work it.

Here's my `company` entity data

```
+++++++++++++++++++
| id  |  name     |
| 1   | company_a |
| 2   | company_b |
+++++++++++++++++++
```

Here's my `sub_agent` entity

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| id   |  company_id | name    |
| 13   |    1        | Google  |
| 14   |    1        | Apple   |
| 15   |    2        | Oracle  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here's my code

On my `branchType.php`

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


class BranchType extends AbstractType {


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

    $builder->add('company_id', EntityType::class, array(
                  'class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Company', 
                  'query_builder' => function (\AppBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository $er) { 
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                         ->where('s.status = 0')
                         ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC');
                    },
                  'choice_label' => 'name', 
                  'placeholder' => 'Select Company',
                ));

    $builder->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();

                    // this would be your entity, i.e. BranchType
                    $data = $event->getData();

                    $company = $data->getCompanyId();

                    $companies = null === $company ? array() : $company->getCompanyId();

                    $form->add('sub_agent_id', EntityType::class, array(
                        'class'       => 'AppBundle\Entity\Sub_agent',
                        'placeholder' => '',
                        'choices'     => $companies,
                    ));
                }
            );

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Company $company = null) {
                $fields = null === $company ? array() : $company->get();

                $form->add('sub_agent_id', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class'       => 'AppBundle\Entity\Sub_agent',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'choices' => $fields,
                ));
            };

    $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getName());
                }
            );            


    $builder->get('company_id')->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                    $outTable = $event->getForm()->getData();
                    $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $company);
                }
            );

     $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                    // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                    $data = $event->getData();

                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getCompanyId());
                }
            );
```

Appreciate the response :)

Comment: The documentation link you quoted is exactly what you need. Replace "sport" by "compagny", and "position" by "sub_agent". What's wrong with your code is "compagny_id" and "sub_agent_id", don't use the id but the entity instead.

Comment: Do i need to change my entity `company_id` and `sub_agent_id` as `company` and `sub_agent`?